# How to prevent the compiler from generating comparison instead of branching instructions?

Tags: c#, bytecode, cil, opcode

Given the following identical properties of branching instructions (from [microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)):

1. **blt**: The effect is **identical** to performing a **clt** instruction followed by a brtrue branch to the specific target instruction.
2. **bgt**: The effect is **identical** to performing a **cgt** instruction followed by a brtrue branch to the specific target instruction
3. **bge**: The effect is **identical** to performing a **clt** instruction (clt.un for floats) followed by a brfalse branch to the specific target instruction.
4. **beq**: The effect is the same as performing a **ceq** instruction followed by a brtrue branch to the specific target instruction.

It turns out that the compiler will usually optimize control flow by translating a boolean operator like '<' into its IL complement branching instruction (clt). Hense it can be the case that on different computers IL code for comparisons can be different. My compiler will always generate the comparison operator however on another PC I saw that it compiled the same code into the branching variant.

I need specific C# examples generating always branching operators (blt/bgt/bge/beq) or always comparison operators (clt/cgt/clt/ceq) followed by a branch true. My my application tests need to be able to assert on this IL-code.

**My attempts:**

- Add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization | MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`
- If/while/for/do-while/switch operations but all result in comparison operators for me.
- Played around with many kinds of examples but unsuccessfully in generating a simple if resulting in branching operators being used.

**Usecase**

I use unit tests that compile a C# file into an assembly, then those tests search for a certain opcode (clt) and find a possible inverse (cgt). This is required for testing a C#-mutation test tool I wrote. This mutation tool mutates (inverts operators) on dll code on byte-level. On C# source code level we use '<' however on IL-bytecode level it can be either clt or blt.

**Resources**

- Microsoft Opcode [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes?view=net-5.0)
- List of Opcode meanings [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)
- Use a tool like IL-spy/Dn-spy for inspecting IL generated instructions.

Comment: If you need specific IL sequences, why are you trying to force the C# compiler to generate them rather than generating them yourself explicitly?

Comment: Don't worry about IL -- worry about the ASM that the JIT generates

Comment: I use unit tests that compile a C# file into an assembly, then they search for a certain opcode (clt) and find a possible inverse (cgt). This is required for testing a C#-mutation test tool I wrote. This mutation tool mutates dll code on byte-level.

Comment: So you're unit-testing a tool which works on IL, and you want to convince the compiler to output specific IL sequences? Don't do that -- that's incredibly dependent on the compiler version. Emit the IL sequences you want to test yourself

Comment: @canton7 Maybe that's what I can do here. I could write some logic that makes sure the right IL-code is there. So if there is no way for me determining the output IL-code while generating I think it would be a good thing to do.

Comment: If you're unit-testing a tool which works on IL sequences, don't involve the compiler at all. Hard-code the IL sequences in your unit test. Involving the compiler makes it an *integration* test -- you'll need some of those as well, but the test there should be "does my tool work on the IL generated by compiler version X for syntax Y", not "does my tool work with IL sequence X". In an integration test you don't care about what the compiler is actually producing

Comment: @canton7 I think for the majority of the usecases this would be fine to do. Opcodes like inverting +, -, *, /, ^, |, & are one-change single change in the Opcode with a library like 'Mono.Cecil'. Tho I do see your argument. I am thinking on how to integrate that since the library works on inspecting an assembly and changing il-code with 'Mono.Ceceil'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a generator that is able to make sure a method definition contains a branching variant instead of the comparison variant. It does this by building up a complete method body for the branching variant. This generator only works on a method as shown in the documentation. Such a method I am using for my tests.

````cs
    /// <summary>
    ///     Generator for a conditional branch statement.
    ///     This generator will only work for the following method structure:
    ///     * Returns true if condition is met
    ///     * Returns false if condition is not met
    ///     * Two int parameters.
    ///     * One if check with the condition.
    ///     ```
    ///     public bool ConditionCheck(int lhs, int rhs)
    ///     {
    ///         if (lhs (ANY CONDITION) rhs)
    ///         {
    ///             return true;
    ///         }
    ///         return false;
    ///     }
    ///     ```
    ///     In some cases the compiler can generate 'comparison' like clt/cgt instead of the branching variants blt/bgt.
    ///     This generator is able to override a method body were an comparison is occurring with the branching variant.
    /// </summary>
    internal class ConditionalBranchGenerator
    {
        private readonly List<Instruction> _instructions;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Generates a new instance by passing in the branching operator that will be used in the generation process.
        ///     Accepts 'only' a branching operators like bgt/blt/beq etc..
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="comparison"></param>
        public ConditionalBranchGenerator(OpCode comparison)
        {
            var ia = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
            var ib = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret);
            var i7 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);

            // load the two parameter booleans
            var i1 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            var i2 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

            // if comparison true branch to i7.
            var i3 = Instruction.Create(comparison, i7);

            // if comparison false load '0' (false) and branch to return. 
            var i4 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
            var i5 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
            var i6 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Br_S, ia);

            var i8 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
            var i9 = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Br_S, ia);

            i1.Next = i2;
            i2.Next = i3;
            i3.Next = i4;
            i4.Next = i5;
            i5.Next = i6;
            i6.Next = i7;
            i7.Next = i8;
            i8.Next = i9;
            i9.Next = ia;
            ia.Next = ib;

            i2.Previous = i1;
            i3.Previous = i2;
            i4.Previous = i3;
            i5.Previous = i4;
            i6.Previous = i5;
            i7.Previous = i6;
            i8.Previous = i7;
            i9.Previous = i8;
            ia.Previous = i9;
            ib.Previous = ia;

            i1.Offset = 0;
            i2.Offset = 1;
            i3.Offset = 2;
            i4.Offset = 3;
            i5.Offset = 4;
            i6.Offset = 5;
            i7.Offset = 6;
            i8.Offset = 7;
            i9.Offset = 8;
            ia.Offset = 9;
            ib.Offset = 10;

            _instructions = new List<Instruction>
            {
                i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, ia, ib
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Replace a method body were a comparison is occurring with the branching variant.
        ///     Note that the method definition must ad-hear to strict rules noted in the class-level comments.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        public void ReplaceMethodInstructions(MethodDefinition method)
        {
            method.Body.Instructions.Clear();

            foreach (var instruction in _instructions)
                method.Body.Instructions.Add(instruction);
        }
    }
````